# Building wix in Visual Studio vs MSBuild - cannot find file

Tags: msbuild, wix

I have a wix project. When I build it from VS it builds perfectly.
In the wix project I use a component dll that the setup needs, it's path is Source="....\Debug\MyDll.dll"

But, when I try to compile this using the build machine, It fails with the error "The system cannot find the file" because the file is binplaced to another location (into the "bin" folder).

I would like to be able to build using VS (on dev machines) and in the build machine. How can I resolve this difference?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [project reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) instead of specifying the path directly. Means, you can reference your DLL project from your WIX project, and then instead of `"..\Debug\MyDll.dll"` use something like `$(var.MyDll.TargetPath)`

Comment: How can i pass that argument differently when i run build from vs and when I run msbuild through tfs?

Comment: Hi, that's not an argument; that's project reference.. that's "Add reference..". Please refer to the docs. This feature was specifically designed to address your issue. Just use it.

Comment: I understand this is a project reference. My question is how do i set $(var.mydll.targetPath) ? It should contain a certain value for VS and another for msbuild from TFS

Comment: It is pre-set by WiX. You don't need to set it. MyDll is the name of the referenced project.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand how it would be set correctly when running msbuild from the TFS...?

Comment: It is set by WiX. Just use it. Do not set it. Please read the above link... I hope it explains it

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you have given above, I think the output path of your project is different between debug and release mode. That's why it is going to "debug\mydll.dll" during debug build and a different folder in release mode.

1. Right click the project file and click on properties.
2. Edit the output path in both debug and release mode to the same folder.
3. Update your WIX file (.wxs) and specify the dll source from this folder.

After this the build should work fine in both local as well as on the server.